# Access the value of a two dimensional array using only one index

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
Configure::write('test', 
array(
    'test1@test.com' =>
        array(
            'test@test.com'=> '1501'),
            ),
);
```

I am trying to get the value of the second array '1501' using only the key of the first array as pointer only. Could anyone suggest something? I am also having a problem using the email as pointer due to the dots.

```
Configure::read('test.test1@test.com');
```

Comment: Can the inner array have more than one element? If so, which element should it get?

Comment: For starters, kill that comma on line 6.

Comment: Even if you could sort out the `.` issue, you would still have an array left, which you would need to access the index at `0` in order to get the value.

Comment: @NateB Why? PHP allows trailing commas in arrays.

Comment: The comma I'm referring to isn't part of an array declaration.  Rather, it's suggesting there's a 3rd argument (not currently defined, of course) for the `write()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Not my version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can Use flatten() function of Set Class.
$arr = array(
    array(
        'Post' => array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'First Post'),
        'Author' => array('id' => '1', 'user' => 'Kyle'),
    ),
    array(
        'Post' => array('id' => '2', 'title' => 'Second Post'),
        'Author' => array('id' => '3', 'user' => 'Crystal'),
    ),
);
$result = Set::flatten($arr);
/* $res now looks like:
    Array (
        [0.Post.id] => 1
        [0.Post.title] => First Post
        [0.Author.id] => 1
        [0.Author.user] => Kyle
        [1.Post.id] => 2
        [1.Post.title] => Second Post
        [1.Author.id] => 3
        [1.Author.user] => Crystal
    )
*/